# Atlassian Connect - Set entity properties in Jira/Cloud

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlassian-connect

I develop an AC/SpringBoot Jira plugin which needs to store properties in the host application. Atlassian provides [Hosted Data Storage](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/hosted-data-storage.html) which I like to use.

I ran a test via [Firefox RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) to play around with this feature.

When issuing a GET request to this URL:

```
https://kuespert-dev.atlassian.net/rest/atlassian-connect/1/addons/<MY-PLUGIN-KEY>
```

while being logged in to my Jira/Cloud instance on another tab everything is fine: I get back information about my plugin, including the key.

However, when issuing a PUT request to set a variable (like described in the documentation mentioned above) using this URL:

```
https://kuespert-dev.atlassian.net/rest/atlassian-connect/1/addons/<MY-PLUGIN-KEY>/properties/testProperty
```

and this request body:

```
{"string":"string-value","number":5}
```

as well as the required header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I get back this response:

```
{
    "status-code": 404,
    "message": "Add-on with key does not exist."
}
```

This is a bit irritating, since the first REST call did find my plugin while the second to the sub-resource did not.

[A similar question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-store-add-on-properties-on-JIRA-cloud-using-REST-Api/qaq-p/614246#U666003) was already asked on the 'Atlassian Community' site, but no solution was found until today.

Maybe it's just a wrong error message or something similar. Does anybody here have experience with the 'Hosted Data Storage' feature and can help?

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: What scopes do you have set in your descriptor file?

Comment: "scopes": [
        "READ",
        "ACT_AS_USER"
    ],

Comment: I think you'll need to add the "WRITE" scope to be able to set entity properties to Jira.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/scopes/scopes.html) states: 'NONE – can access add-on defined data' - I believe that this includes the hosted data. Meanwhile I was able to successfully set and read data programmatically via Java. However when trying to access the stored data in the browser I always get this 'Add-on with key does not exist' message. Strange.